# How to get out of a forEach loop once a value is true using firebase and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check usernames to see if they are available while the user types into the input. I can get the value, the problem is that it just switches back to false because there are other usernames that do not match the input.

```
const usernameRef = firebase.database().ref('usernames');
    if (event.target.value) {
      usernameRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(snap => {
         //snap.val() is each of the usernames in the db
          if (snap.val() === username) {
            this.setState({
              disabled: true
            });

            return;
          }

          if (snap.val() !== username) {
            this.setState({
              disabled: false
            });
          }
        });
      });
    }
```

The input is just a basic input which calls a function onChange that activates this part of the code. Everything works and it does set the state to true when the user types in a username that exist, but then it loops through the rest of the usernames and sets it back to false. I figured the `return` would take care of that, but it did not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `.forEach()`, you could just do `Array.prototype.find()`.

```
const existingUsername = snapshot.val().find(u => u === username);

if(existingUsername) {
    this.setState({ disabled: true });
} else {
    this.setState({ disabled: false });
}
```

Comment: Mine is an object in which the uid is the key and the value is the username. I ended up doing `Object.values(snapshot.val()).includes(username)` to test if the username was there or not. Same concept though. I like this approach better since im not sure you can "exit" out of a forEach

Comment: @TaylorAustin awesome; glad you found something that works well for your usecase